# How can I crop and resize a image?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to crop out and resize the head of Steve, the default skin for Minecraft! :-)

But I'm having some problems, I got the cropping down, but the resizing does not work and the image is all blurry :-(

My XAML:

```
<Image Height="60" Width="60" Name="ProfileImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

My code behind:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle cropRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(8,8,8,8);
        Bitmap source = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("steve.png") as Bitmap;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(60, 60);

        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.DrawImage(source, 
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), 
                cropRect, 
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Dispose();

           ProfileImage.Source = CreateBitmapSourceFromBitmap(target);
        }
    }

    public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue? The skin looks like this, and the head portion I want is (8,8,8 (width),8 (height)):

[image]

Comment: When you say "blury" do you mean pixelated? If you resize an 8px x 8px image to 60px x 60px, it is going to look pixelated, you are just making the pixels bigger.

Comment: The problem is that is not "pixelated", instead of a sharp image it looks like someone splashed water on non-waterressistent paint :D

Comment: Not entirely sure what that would look like but it sounds like it is interpolating to try and smooth the edges of the larger pixels. Do you actually want a pixelated image rather than an interpolated one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to retain the square pixel shape when resizing then you simply need to change the interpolation mode of the `Graphics` object you are using to do the drawing :

```
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

g.DrawImage(source,
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
            cropRect,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Below shows the `NearestNeighbor` interpolation on the left and the `Default` (Bilinear) interpolation on the right.

[image]

Comment: Was totally NearestNeighbor what I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without any WinForms (System.Drawing) stuff by setting `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` to `NearestNeighbor` on the Image control

```
<Image Height="60" Width="60" Name="ProfileImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
```

and using a `CroppedBitmap` for the Image's `Source`:

```
var steve = new BitmapImage(new Uri("steve.png", UriKind.Relative));
ProfileImage.Source = new CroppedBitmap(steve, new Int32Rect(8, 8, 8, 8));
```

---

You might even do it entirely in XAML:

```
<Image Height="60" Width="60" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="steve.png" SourceRect="8,8,8,8"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Your solution for doing it in entirely in XAML was nice :-)

Comment: Yes, it saves a lot of code-behind. And seriously, you should avoid that WinForms stuff.